# Click function in JS / jQuery (Score keeper)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am new in here and I have an issue with my code. I am new in coding and I studied this by myself so my code might be not up to date.

Basically I want to have a function when I click something a point will be added to my score. My code is to build few ul with few li and some of them will turn green when I click and some red. I have managed to write a code to have the points add to the score when I press a button but what if I want to have only point for the buttons which will give me a green color and also will be working only once (once turned green it will no longer add points).

What I have achieved is that I can get the score up to winning score which I set up and every span I press is giving me points either if it is red or green  or not chosen yet. I can press more times on one span and it keeps counting. I have an issue with adding a proper condition in if statement in JS code where I can specify that only spans which are the correct answer will give me points (the ones which will turn green) and the wrong answers (the ones which will turn red) will not give me any points.

I have been playing with this for a while and I have got so many different errors every time when I try something I hope someone can help me with this one, I would really appreciate it :) I will paste the code  in 3 sections: HTML, CSS and JS.

```js
var correct = document.querySelectorAll(".correct");
var wrong = document.querySelector(".wrong");
var span = document.querySelectorAll("span");
var green = document.querySelector(".green");
var red = document.querySelector(".red");
var li = document.querySelectorAll("li");
var score = document.querySelector("#scoreDisplay");
var currentScore = 0;
var winningScore = 12;
var choice = document.querySelectorAll("span");

for (var i = 0; i < choice.length; i++) {
  choice[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (currentScore !== winningScore) {
      currentScore +
    } else {
    }
    score.textContent = currentScore;
  });
}

$(".correct").on("click", function(event) {
  $(this).parent().addClass("green");
  event.stopPropagation();
  if ($(this).parent().css("background-color") === "rgb(242, 242, 242)") {
    $(this).parent().css("background-color", "rgb(102, 255, 102)");
    event.stopPropagation();
  } else {
  }
});

$(".wrong").click(function(event) {
  if ($(this).parent().css("background-color") === "rgb(102, 255, 102)") {
  } else {
    $(this).parent().addClass("red");
    event.stopPropagation();
    
    if ($(this).parent().css("background-color") === "rgb(242, 242, 242)") {
      $(this).parent().css("background-color", "rgb(255, 0, 0)");
      event.stopPropagation();
    } else {
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Roboto;
  background: #2BC0E4;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #EAECC6, #2BC0E4);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #EAECC6, #2BC0E4);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

nav {
  margin-bottom: 7em;
}

#nr {
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  padding-left: 130px;
  color: white;
}

h6 {
  color: white;
}

.title {
  background: #66ccff;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  background: #fff;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: 665;
}

li:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
}

.fa-medapps {
  float: right;
}

#list {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.cont {
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 150px;
  padding-left: 100px
}

.container {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.yesno {
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px
}

.yesno:hover {
  background-color: #ff9900;
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.yesno2 {
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-right: 3px;
  color: #99ff33;
}

.yesno2:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.fa-check {
  color: #66ff66;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.3s linear;
  opacity: 0;
}

.fa-exclamation {
  color: red;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.3s linear;
  opacity: 0;
}

.green {
  background-color: rgb(102, 255, 102);
}

.red {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scenarios.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark pb-10">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="../Kamishibai.html">Home</a>
  <h2 class="d-flex justify-content-center">KAMISHIBAI</h4>
  <h6 class="d-flex justify-content-end">Created by Kamil Opalinski</h6>
</nav>
<h1 id="nr" class="display-2 mb-5">Scenario1</h1>
<hr>

<!-- QUESTION 1 -->
<div class="cont">
  <h1 class="title">1/4 TEST<i class="fab fa-medapps"></i></h1>
  <ul>
    <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i><i class="fas fa-exclamation"></i>Question1<span class="yesno correct">NO</span><span class="yesno wrong">YES</span></li>
    <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i><i class="fas fa-exclamation"></i>Question2<span class="yesno wrong">NO</span><span class="yesno correct">YES</span></li>
    <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i><i class="fas fa-exclamation"></i>Question3<span class="yesno wrong">NO</span><span class="yesno correct">YES</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- QUESTION 2 -->
<div class="cont">
  <h1 class="title">2/4 TEST<i class="fab fa-medapps"></i></h1>
  <ul>
    <li><span class="ml-2">Question1</span><span class="yesno">NO</span><span class="yesno">YES</span></li>
    <li><span class="ml-2">Question2</span><span class="yesno">NO</span><span class="yesno">YES</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- QUESTION 3 -->
<div class="cont">
  <h1 class="title">3/4 TEST<i class="fab fa-medapps"></i></h1>
  <ul>
    <li><span class="ml-2">Question1</span><span class="yesno">NO</span><span class="yesno">YES</span></li>
    <li><span class="ml-2">Question2</span><span class="yesno">NO</span><span class="yesno">YES</span></li>
    <li><span class="ml-2">Question3</span><span class="yesno">NO</span><span class="yesno">YES</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- QUESTION 4 -->
<div class="cont">
  <h1 class="title">4/4 TEST<i class="fab fa-medapps"></i></h1>
  <ul>
    <li><span class="ml-2">Question1</span><span class="yesno">NO</span><span class="yesno">YES</span></li>
    <li><span class="ml-2">Question2</span><span class="yesno">NO</span><span class="yesno">YES</span></li>
    <li><span class="ml-2">Question3</span><span class="yesno">NO</span><span class="yesno">YES</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h1 class="d-flex justify-content-center">SCORE
    <p id="scoreDisplay"> 0</p> /12
  </h1>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: java to javascript is like ham to hamster. They are **not** the same

Comment: There's a lot of code here and difficult to tell exactly what your issue/question is.  One thing to note is this `.css("background-color") === "rgb(242, 242, 242)"`  where `.css("background-color")` will out differently in different browsers.   Instead, add a `class` and check for that class, eg `if ($(this).parent().hasClass("red")) { $(this).parent().toggleClass("red green"); }` to remove red and add green.

Comment: I would also suggest having only one class, with the other the default - eg if it starts as "red" then `.yesno { background-color: red } .yesno.green { background-color: green }` then you only need to check `if (!$(..).hasClass("green"))` (note the `!` for "isn't green") and add/remove `green` without needing to worry about `red` (whichever way makes sense for you)

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank you for your feedback, Just to explain it in more details: I have the li items as a table where each of them have #fff background color and every second li element has rgb(242, 242, 242). The red and green are hidden at first. My main problem here is in the for loop, in if condition (currentScore !== winningScore) I am trying to add another condition where only runs if the li elements are not green or red. I have tried something like li.css.background = !green or li.classList("correct") = true. Note that this part is not written in jQuery, I would appreciate a hint

Comment: Issue has been solved:

Comment: $(".correct").on("click", function (event) {
  $(this).parent().addClass("green");
  if (currentScore !== winningScore && !this.classList.contains("checked")) {
    currentScore++;
    $(this).addClass("checked");
    score.textContent = currentScore;
  }
 
  event.stopPropagation();
 
  if ($(this).parent().css("background-color") === "rgb(242, 242, 242)") {
    $(this).parent().css("background-color", "rgb(102, 255, 102)");
 
    event.stopPropagation();
  } else {
  }
});